# Transparent div on top of image

Tags: html, css, transparency

I have a transparent div on top of an image. I want that this div will hide the image even though

it is transparent. I've tried using z-index, but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Tried to use `z-index:1;` property, but not working.
Link to jsfidle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Z7u8S/3/

What I'm tring to accomplish is that I have an unsorted list with lots of list items.
By touch swiping on a div I want that the div (with image) under it will reveal.
The problem is that the upper div's background  needs to be transparent, otherwise I have no problem to do it.

Comment: How can something transparent hide something that's behind? A transparent div is just like glass

Comment: Share code or fiddle it

Comment: Are you trying something like `opacity: 0`? [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/ENPb5/)

Comment: Do you mean a transparent div overlay on top of image?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Z7u8S/3/
This is an example.
I want by swiping text_div to reveal the img div by using left:XXpx
on text_div. I need that the img_div will stay in the same postion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is better to just hide the image by setting the css for the image to "visiblity:hidden"  rather than using another element to cover it.

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/yuH7E/

```
<img style="visibility:hidden;" src="whatever" />
```

Comment: I need that the image will stay on the same position, so when I use jquery swipe on one div, the image reveals under the text div

Comment: the image will maintain position using this css (different than display:none). it is better to wait until your swipe event is finished and then set the visibility css property to a value of visible.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant overlay, then try this. Used hover effect to demonstrate it.

CSS:

```
.checked{position:relative;width:200px;height:200px;border:1px solid red;}
.checked img{max-width:100%;}
.checked div{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;opacity:0.6;background:transparent;}
.checked:hover div{background:#BFBFBF;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="checked">
    <img src="http://www.vacul.org/extension/site/design/site//images/anonymous-user.png" />
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/183/

Answer (score 0):

Just try as follows 
HTML

```
<div id="mask"> <img src="http://arcadeflip.com/styles/acidtech/imageset/logo.png"> </div>
```

CSS

```
    #mask{
background-color:red;
    z-index:2;
}
img{
 position:relative;
z-index:-1;
}
```

CHECK http://jsfiddle.net/arshidkv12/S6dHS/